# How to pass data from Layout component to children in Gatsby V2?

Tags: gatsby

In v1, I used to pass props to children using something like this:

`children({ ...this.props, foo: bar })`

But in Gatsby v2, children is not a function:
`Uncaught TypeError: children is not a function`

I saw children is an array of objects so I tried to add a prop to every object in the children array using map (also tried forEach):

`const childrenWithProps = children.map(child => child.foo = bar)`

But I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property foo, object is not extensible`

What's the v2 way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is a proper way in regard of Gatsby V2, but you could try to use [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

I've done something like this:

**in ./src/components/Layout.js**:

```
import React from 'react';

const foo = 'bar';

export default ({ children }) => {
  return(
  <div>
    {children(foo)}
  </div>
)};
```

**in ./src/pages/index.js**:

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default (props) => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      {foo => (
        <div>
          {foo}
        </div>
      )}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `React.Children.map` in order to map an array of React components, and you need to use `React.cloneElement` to modify the props:

```
React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => (
  React.cloneElement(child, {
    foo: "bar",
  })
))
```

For what it's worth, this isn't related to Gatsby, it's just the way React works.